# Display the JSON response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsp

How to display the JSON response in jsp page through ajax...

```
   function doAjaxPost() {    
     var name = $('#name').val();
     var password = $('#password').val();
     var gender = $('#gender').val();
     var aboutYou = $('#aboutYou').val();


       $.ajax({  
       type: "POST", 
       url: "add.htm",
       data: "name=" + name + "&password=" + password + "&gender=" + gender + "&aboutYou=" + aboutYou, 
       success: function(response){
         alert('name : '+response);



          },  
       error: function(e){  
       alert('Error: ' + e);  
    }  
  });
```

Here in this  alert('name : '+response); I get the response ,but i want to display on this jsp page.. This is form data which i have to display...plz help..thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show us what `response` actually looks like? Knowing the structure of the JSON is the first thing before you can do anything with it.

Comment: {"name":"mohit","password":"1234"},{"name":"mohit","password":"1234"},{"name":"mohit","password":"1234"},

Comment: Wooh, do you actually save the password in clear text??!!! That's stupid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse the json data using json parser and then populate tables..!

```
  var resultData = JSON.parse(response);
 //resultDate will ve json object in the form of JS objects 
  resultData.membervalues (or arrays)
```

Comment: thanks , but plz tell me here how to populate the table

Comment: try to post json then only can give you details..!.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... I don't understand your problem. What do you want to display and where? Create a  on your page where you want and replace your alert with:

```
$('#myResponce').html(responce);
```

is this what you want?

Comment: create jsfiddle for your situation. I dont understand you. You want to fill your form with this data? Then `$('#name').val(responce);`, for example